# Call to methods btwn two different classes

Tags: java, math, bluej

Here are the instructions for this assignment: http://textuploader.com/55z48

For an assignment I need to read an input text file and evaluate the triangle based on the data found in the text file which consists of an unknown number of groups of 3 numbers (Each group representing a different triangle). According to the project specifications I need to have a main method and several other methods. I'm going to post my two classes below.

I think I have the **Triangle** Class set up correctly with the exception of the floatEqual. How do i incorporate this into both my isEquilateral and isIsosceles methods?

```
public class Triangle
{

    public static double computePerimeter(double num1, double num2, double num3)
    {
        return num1 + num2 + num3;
    }

    public static boolean isEquilateral(double num1, double num2, double num3)
    {
        return num1 == num2 && num2 == num3;
    }

    public static boolean isIsosceles(double num1, double num2, double num3)
    {
        return num1 == num2 || num2 == num3 || num1 == num3;
    }

    public static void triangleType(double num1, double num2, double num3)
    {
        if(isEquilateral(num1,num2,num3) == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Equilateral");
        }
        if(isIsosceles(num1,num2,num3) == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Isosceles");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Scalene");
        }
    }
}
```

---

The code below is my **TriangleEvaluator** class and I'm supposed to call methods from the **Triangle** Class. But I'm confused how to achieve this. I think I have code in there that is no necessary, but i'm not sure. I was working on all of this last night and was going to finish it today and some how i can't seem to get back into java mode.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriangleEvaluator
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("triData.txt"));    
        double num1 = 0;
        double num2 = 0;
        double num3 = 0;
        double perim = 0;
        while (in.hasNextDouble())
        { 
            num1 = in.nextDouble();
            num2 = in.nextDouble();
            num3 = in.nextDouble();

            perim = computePerimeter(num1, num2, num3);
            System.out.println(perim);
        }
    }

    public static boolean floatEquals(double num1, double num2)
    {
        double Err = 0.00000001;
        if(Math.abs(num1 - num2) < Err)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static double computePerimeter(double num1, double num2, double num3)
    {
        double perimeter;
        perimeter = (num1 + num2 + num3);
        return perimeter;
    }
}
```

This an example of the inputs:

```
18.7 30 18.7
3 4 5
20.72 20.72 20.72
```

**and the desired output:**

```
18.7 30.0 18.7
Perimeter: 67.40
Isosceles

3.0 4.0 5.0
Perimeter: 12.00
Scalene

20.7 20.7 20.7
Perimeter: 62.16
Equilateral
```

Thanks in advance (I by no means intend anyone to just do my assignment for me, so please forgive me if it seems that way - thank you!)
Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like the `TriangleEvaluator` class should contain static methods that evaluate a triangle for its type. Im assuming the three fields in your Triangle class are floats; the point of floatEquals then is to test their equality

Comment: Actually. Reread your specs again. It highlights **exactly** how to do this program

Comment: Triangle should have **no static anything** except maybe `floatEquals`. It should have a constructor -- yours has none. Re-read the spec as per @BenKnoble's statement above, but read it critically since you seem to be ignoring most of what is told to you in those specs.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i wish i could up vote that comment 10 times....

Comment: Well, @HovercraftFullOfEels comment explains at least one step you can take. Static methods are more utility methods; you need to think of your triangle class as an object which can report back whether or not is isosceles or equilateral etc

Comment: Do **NOT** deface your question please. Question rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

If the Triangle and TriangleEvaluator are in the same package (I.E usually just the same directory), you can call the static methods from Triangle by specifying the class before the method.

Triangle.isIsoceles(1.0, 2.0, 3.0).

If they are not in the same package you must import the Triangle class like you did java.io. However you almost certainly wont need to import Triangle.

This only works for static methods. If the methods are dynamic (don't have static in the method declaration) you must create a Triangle object using the (currently not specified) triangle constructor. Then you can call them via myTriangleObject.aMethod()